# Getting a "Access to the path ... is denied" when trying to publish my ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, publishing

I'm trying to publish an old ASP.NET WebForms app we have. I'm publishing it to a folder on my development box (a Windows 7 Ultimate box, 32-bit). When I try to publish it, I get the following error message:

Access to the path 'C:\Users\Rod\AppData\Local\Temp\~184a\bin\App_global.asax.compiled' is denied.

I'm sure that this path is temporary, only there long enough to perform the publish, but it's stopping me cold. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen when the file is currently in use by a process on the server. More than likely IIS. Try recycling the app pool that the application is running in, or stopping the site long enough to publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the permissions on the file. Make sure it is shared to who it needs to be.

To do this, navigate to the file in the directory, right click and go to properties, then make sure the read only button is not filled in.

Comment: I tried to find the file, but couldn't. My guess is that it's so transient that it is only created long enough to perform the publish.